# Cannot setup superbase db connection

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I am using the connection string copied straign out of superbase

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = 'https://sgjnykuknyykwstchued.supabase.co'
const supabaseKey = process.env.SUPABASE_KEY
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)
```

when my sveltkit app is running I get the following error

```
supabaseUrl is required.
```

I am confusted as the superbaseUrl is clearly in the code

Comment: what's the full error stacktrace? seems like the app can't access that code.. did you try some console logs or debugger statements to check where it could be going wrong?